# Grafana auto refresh dashboard layout/panels?

Tags: grafana

When using Grafana, we have it up on some TVs. Does anyone know a way to make it so it'll auto-refresh not just the data, but the actual dashboard if someone adds a panel, changes layout, etc...?

We get real tired of constantly asking for people with remote access to log in and reload the browser. :)

Answer (score 9):

In your dash board you can find a option to select refresh time period. In default settings it is set to off. You can select a refresh period and then it will start to auto refresh.

You can find out the refresh option at the right side of the options bar of your dashboard.See image below.

[image]

In my case I have set it into 1sec.

[image]

Comment: these settings are in the editing of the panels

Comment: OP is asking about how to reload the whole dashboard (not just the data). Sometimes panels get changed or new panels are added - it would be nice to have them update on TVs.

Answer (score -1):

How about using Chrome extension application? I recommend using this method. I'm using this extension too.

**Super Auto Refresh Plus**

[image]

url : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-auto-refresh-plus/globgafddkdlnalejlkcpaefakkhkdoa

> Super Auto Refresh Plus is the most user friendly auto refresh and auto reload website extension on the chrome web store market. Super Auto Refresh Plus helps you auto refresh and auto reload any pages and website with selected time interval in just one single click.

Comment: This is not what the question is about. Plus the whole backend would be reloaded, which is not Grafana's purpose

Comment: I know this is not an accurate answer. However, auto refresh whole dashboard is not supported now in the grafana. That is why it is proposed as an alternative.